# how to change a state of a component without rendering

Tags: reactjs

i have a header component has a state [noti,setnoti] and im using sessionstoarge that return nombre of items and i want when the sessionsstorage value change i want state do upadate .

*this the code in the header*

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        const list=sessionStorage.getItem('panier');
        if(list)
        {
            setnoti(Object.keys(JSON.parse(list)).length);
        }
    })
```

*the App.js*

```
       <>
         <Header/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
                <Route path="/Details/:userId" element={<Details/>} />
                <Route path="/Panier" element={<Panier/>} />
                <Route path="/*" element={<PageNotFound/>} />
            </Routes>
         <Footer/>      
        </>
```

*Remarque*

1. the sessionstorage change by another components . and the probleme  the
   header doesnt render to make upd

2.the header render just one time when the app is load

Comment: If you want the useEffect to trigger only when sessionStorage change you can specify your useEffect : `useEffect(() => { fcnt... }, [sessionStorage])`

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
        const list=sessionStorage.getItem('panier');
        if(list)
        {
            setnoti(Object.keys(JSON.parse(list)).length);

        }
    },[sessionStorage]) not work

Comment: i have this componenet in the root main <Header/>
                 <Main/>
              <Footer/>  that means Header render one time when the page is loading and the sessionstoarge change only in the Main

Comment: What if you dispatch the you sessionStorgae in the global store of your application ? Then the header will render each time it changes

Comment: yes but ididnt use redux

Comment: Not sure you'll be able to do this without redux and the store. Looks like we can't hook the sessionStorage change

Comment: could u explain more to me

Comment: If you need to catch all the update of your sessionStorage in multiple components you should create the globalStore of your application. Then you can dispatch updates and subscribe to updates in every component you need easily: https://redux.js.org/api/createstore